# How to track Outbound links without breaking links to affiliate templates with no GA code

Tags: google-analytics, hyperlink, event-tracking, outbound

I have hundreds of affiliate templates and when I change the GA file, it applies to all the templates.

If I want to track outbound links, I have no choice but to put the GA javascript code in all my templates, as well as the outbound links.

**Javascript is this:**

```
<script> 
 var trackOutboundLink = function(url) { 
 ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, { 
     'transport': 'beacon', 
 'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;} 
 });
 }
 </script>
```

My understanding is that the outbound link (like below) will break if the GA tracking code is not included on a template (i.e. UA-#######-#) :

```
 <a  href="https://linktotrack.com"  onclick="trackOutboundLink('https://linktotrack.com')">Track this link</a>
```

Some of the affiliates do not have or want their GA code (i.e. UA-#######-#) included in the template.

Is there a way to set up outbound tracking without breaking the links on templates without GA code?

Thank you.

Comment: Without the tracking ID i.e. UA -XXX. GA would not be able to send the info for anything. You have to match the info with the GA account, tracking ID helps to do it,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a **Measurement Protocol** hit to send the data without using GA code.

The Google Analytics Measurement Protocol allows developers to make HTTP requests to send raw user interaction data directly to Google Analytics servers

The hit looks something like this

```
www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fhome
```

Where tid =Tracking ID / Property ID.

Learn more about the measurement protocol here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide

Comment: great idea but this would not work because the link is universal for all affiliates.